# Create automatically table with hibernate in spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have spring boot application . I will create and update table automatically in java application but my code doesn't work.

This is application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/exchange
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

This my model.I use generic class that all model use from it.

I will create table of this model .

Please help me .

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Users extends Generic {

}

@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Generic implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "createdBy")
    private Long createdBy=-1L;

    @Column(name = "updatedBy")
    private Long updatedBy=-1L;

    @Column(name = "createdDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "updatedDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedDate;
}
```

Comment: well it's seems like you should change an _update_ value to _create-drop_ or smth like this. Here is a [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties)

Comment: I set create-drop but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `@Table` annotation on the POJO that should be persisted, eg add `@Table(name = "users")` on your `Users` class

Comment: I think @Table annotation is just to specify a new name rather than entity name.